# Cannot use Express custom error handling with next() as it is not passed in Bull job

Tags: node.js, express, bull

I'm trying to pass `next()` function to Bull job so I can handle asynchronous error handling with Express.

For some reason, it won't get forwarded.

This is is the route. data includes `domain` and `next()` which get passed to the *Queue*

```
crawler.post("/sitemap",async (req,res,next)=>{
        const {domain} = req.body
        const data = {domain,next}
        const response = await generateSitemapQueue(data)
        return res.json({message:`task has been added to the queue successfully...`,...response})
})
```

Queue simply adds data to the worker

```
sitemapQueue.process(createSitemapForDomain)

export const generateSitemapQueue = async (data) => {
  sitemapQueue.add(data)
}
// Here next can still be accessible in data
```

Not at worker, `next()` is undefined and cannot be called but domain is accessible. Why is that?

```
export const createSitemapForDomain = async (job,done)=>{
    const {domain,next} = job.data
    // next is undefined and cannot be called
}
```

Comment: You can't store functions in Redis.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you. I need to figure out how to leverage express custom error handling for asynchronous bull tasks. There is `done(new Error())` but this will only cause worker to fail. I guess this is the only option going forward. Have one try catch block in worker and throw errors via `done()`

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to add that clarification.

Comment: @MatijaŽiberna if the job would fail and you would have been able to pass the error back to Express, you'd get an Express error anyway because you already sent back a response. Perhaps it's possible to pass back a job id to the frontend and periodically check the status of that job (and notify the user if it failed).